# php tag data not executing when retrieving from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want  to use the base url to display the image in the content. so i am storing follwing text in the database

```
<p>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url; ?>images/abc.jpg" />
</p>
```

when i display the content on the page the the php tag is not executing , it displays only `<img src="<?php echo base_url; ?>images/abc.jpg" />`. please help me.

Comment: And the answer to your question is that your web server is not interpreting the page as php. What web server are you using? And does it have a module or component installed for interpreting php?

Comment: @ben lee i am using apache. it is executing php tags but when i am fetching the text which contain the php tag then only i have problem

Comment: Oh, you're actually literally storing that string in the database? That's not the right way to do this at all. I'll post an answer explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing that in database would not work, as php tags are not evaluated by `echo`.

For what you vant to do there are 2 ways.

First, Store the image url only then output it like this in PHP

```
echo '<img src="' . $base_url . $url_from_db . '"/>';
```

Second, also in this store just the image url. And use the HTML BASE tag to make a URL the BASE url for all relative URLs on your HTML page. Like this:
In your  element put this

```
<base href="<?php echo $base_url ?>">
```

And use following for image output

```
<p><img src="<?php echo $img_orl_from_db ?>" /></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need preprocess your page before output. Something like this:

in database:

```
<p > <img src="{{BASEURL}}images/abc.jpg" /></p>
```

in php code:

```
$output = getOutput(); // Get your output string from database
$baseURLPattern = '{{BASEURL}}';
echo preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($baseURLPattern) . '/', $yourBaseURL, $output);
```

**[updated]**

Simple example which works as is:

```
$output = '<p > <img src="{{BASEURL}}images/abc.jpg" /></p>';
$baseURLPattern = '{{BASEURL}}';
$yourBaseURL = 'http://www.example.com/';
echo preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($baseURLPattern) . '/', $yourBaseURL, $output);
```

Comment: Of course this will not work as is without defining of getOutput() and $yourBaseURL.

Comment: :) i can understand that much

Answer (score 1):

If you are using codeigniter, see the config file. Set the base_url from there.
base_url() is a function, you lack '()' in your syntax

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/images/abc.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing that whole code block in the database. Instead store just the filename part. For example, your database might have a filename column with rows like:

```
abc.jpg
xyz.jpg
```

Then your php render the rest, like this

```
<?php
    // Get your $row
    ?>
        <p>
            <img src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>images/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" />
        </p>
    <?php
    // Continue with your code
?>
```

*You'll change 'filename' in `$row['filename']` to whatever your column name is.*